# ASP.NET HttpHandler vs IIS handler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I've defined an HTTP Handler and added an entry in my web.config

```
<add verb="GET" path="TestApp/*" type="TestApp.TestHandler, TestWebApp" />
```

This works as I would expect EXCEPT when I encounter static resources eg JPG, PNG files

I need my handler to also handle paths like TestApp/logo.gif but it seems like IIS has the StaticHandler registered to intercept these requests

Is there any way for my ASP.NET HttpHandler to have a chance to handle requests for static resources ONLY for the path TestApp/* but letting the IIS StaticHandler handle everything else?

And yes I realize that letting IIS handle static resources with its own handler is faster and more efficient

Comment: Try setting path="TestApp/*.*". I don't think you need to change anything in IIS for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler will intercept those requests if you are running in integrated pipeline mode:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="TestHandler" path="TestApp/*" verb="GET" type="TestApp.TestHandler, TestWebApp" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

If you are running in Classic Pipeline mode you will have to register an ISAPI filter in IIS in order to make those requests go through the managed handler.

Comment: I am running in Classic Pipeline mode - I guess the only option I have is to register an ISAPI filter in IIS then.

Comment: Yes, that's the only option. By the way is there any reason why you are running in Classic Mode in IIS7? This was viable in IIS6, but in your place I would definitely consider switching to integrated pipeline mode.

Comment: It's a large, existing application in a bureaucratic environment unfortunately where changes to the eco-system are prohibited without long campaigning and forms on forms on forms to be submitted

Comment: I understand. Been there. And left :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to your web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

This will ensure that even requests for static files are being passed through the .net pipeline.

Comment: I would recommend against doing that. If you are running in integrated pipeline mode it's better to register the handler for a specific path only instead of making ALL requests going through the managed pipeline which could have a performance impact on your application.

Comment: Well, he mentioned "I realize that letting IIS handle static resources with its own handler is faster and more efficient", so that's why I'm saying that this is a possibility.